# Error when deploying to Heroku via github

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I've been trying to deploy my first Ruby on Rails application to Heroku to test it out and I receive the following error when using the manual deploy option. Just for some background notes I created the rails application using the operating system 'Windows 10', Ruby version 2.1.8p440 & Rails 4.2.5.1. If anymore information I will be happy to provide, thank you. I also have 'coffee-script-source' installed as a gem and its to make the project run correctly.

**----- HEROKU MANUAL DEPLOY LOG START -----**

```
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

!
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

**----- HEROKU MANUEL DEPLOY LOG END -----**

Comment: Did you read *sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.* and the linked page in the Heroku docs? Heroku suggests PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `sqlite3` gem under development group

```
group :development, :test do     
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Add `pg` gem under production group

```
group :production do    
  gem 'pg'
end
```

run `bundle` and try to push code to Heroku.

Comment: Ok thank you LHH for this it seems to have worked perfectly the push from github to heroku gave no errors, however when I try to view the app it gives me the following error. **http://prntscr.com/aepg5c**